# Bluemix returns different result for querying Cloudant database

Tags: ibm-cloud, strongloop, cloudant

I have a Strongloop instance running on Bluemix.
I have the same Strongloop running in one of my VM local.
They two synchronize through git.

My query code 100% works for querying Cloudant and outputting the query URL and param.
When I run param in Cloudant console, it returns data.
When I run the URL in Postman (Chrome app), it returns the same data.
I committed the code to Bluemix and restarted the Strongloop instance.
Code on Bluemix then works fine as tested on local. I still have the URL and param output in Bluemix log.
After a few hours when I access the Strongloop API, it returns nothing. No error but a normal JSON {docs:[]}.
I got the log of this query from Bluemix log and ran the URL in Postman and also ran the param in Cloudant console. They both return correct records.

Anyone had a similar issue before?

Comment: Restart will temporarily fix it but won't last long.

Comment: Odd. Can you post any logs you have associated with this database call?

Comment: It's gone now. Weird.